# How to install yolo3 library in python

Tags: python, keras, yolo

I am trying to install yolo3 library in python. But, it does not. I typed `pip install yolo3`

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement yolo3 (from versions: none)'
ERROR: No matching distribution found for yolo3

Comment: yolo3 is not a library that you can install with pip.

Comment: However, this is not the case when using pip3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yolo34py comes in 2 variants, CPU Only Version and GPU Version. Installation may take a while since it involves downloading and compiling of darknet.

**CPU Only Version**

```
pip3 install yolo34py
```

**GPU Version:**

```
pip3 install yolo34py-gpu
```

pypi Reference : https://pypi.org/project/yolo34py/

Comment: please try this
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install "package-name"